# Android Intent putExra data does not work on retriever side

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I am new to Android,
I am updating a TextView on Widget with the help of configuration Activity. It works fine. Same text view needs to be updated to refresh button click. For that I am passing Widget ID through Intent but on receiver side unable to receiver widget ID and hence Text view could not be updated.

Setting up Intent, in Widget_Provider

```
Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(context, refreshWidgetActivity.class);
refreshIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH);
PendingIntent refreshPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
refreshIntent, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button3, refreshPendingIntent);
refreshIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,appWidgetIds[0]);
```

On received Activity end,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
}

if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
finish();
}
```

Here 0 is found in extras instead of Widget ID, Please help.

Comment: No, Error seen in LogCat

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `putExtra` before you create the `PendingIntent`?

Like this:

```
Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(context, refreshWidgetActivity.class);
refreshIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH);
refreshIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,appWidgetIds[0]);
PendingIntent refreshPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
refreshIntent, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button3, refreshPendingIntent);
```

Comment: Sorry bro, Again problem. 1st time configuration activity retrieves Widget ID is different than retrieved on Refresh button and hence Text View of widget not updated. for configuration activity its 47 & for refresh button its 7

Comment: Have you tried using some of the PendingIntent flags? Maybe PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT will to the trick.

Comment: How to use these FLags,may you please provide any refference.

Comment: You can always read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29). Basically you just pass them in the last argument to PendingIntent#getActivity

Comment: Great, finally it works & My text view update. Thanks for all to help

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to manage some flags.

If I correctly understood your problem, you're trying to update data in your Activity passing it extras.

You don't set any FLAG for your Intent. Also, I don't really know where is your Intent and how it is launched. However, for a same kind of problem in my own application, I use this solution :

**I set my Intent with two flags :**

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

In this way, my Intent will launch a new task (FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), then it will clear it to its root state (FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) (see Sources to understand why).

**Then, my PendingIntent was set to cancel the current, to be sure there is only one instance launched (no need more I think)**

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

In this way, the new Intent will launch a new task, clear all previous data and take the new ones. The PendingIntent is not uselessly duplicated.

It works for my case, and I think it should work for yours. If any enhancements can be added, please tell me.

Sources : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP